# read single bit operation python 2.6

Tags: python, binary, bit-manipulation

I am trying to read a single bit in a binary string but can't seem to get it to work properly. I read in a value then convert to a 32b string. From there I need to read a specific bit in the string but its not always the same. getBin function returns 32bit string with leading 0's. The code I have always returns a 1, even if the bit is a 0. Code example:

```
slot=195035377
getBin = lambda x, n: x >= 0 and str(bin(x))[2:].zfill(n) or "-" + str(bin(x))[3:].zfill(n)
bits = getBin(slot,32)
bit = (bits and (1 * (2 ** y)) != 0)
print("bit: %i\n"%(bit))
```

in this example `bits = 00001011101000000000000011110011`

and if I am looking for bit3 which `i` s a 0, bit will be equal to 1. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to use `format(slot, ' 032b')` instead to format your binary number.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 223
bitpos = 3
bit3 = (n >> (bitpos-1))&1
```

is how you should be doing it ... don't use strings!

Comment: You want to shift twice, not three times.

Answer (score 1):

To test for specific bits in a integer value, use the `&` bitwise operand; no need to convert this to a binary string.

```
if slot & (1 << 3):
    print 'bit 3 is set'
else:
    print 'bit 3 is not set'
```

The above code shifts a test bit to the left twice. Alternatively, shift `slot` to the right 3 times:

```
if (slot >> 2) & 1:
```

To make this generic for *any* bit position, subtract 1:

```
if slot & (1 << (bitpos - 1)):
    print 'bit {} is set'.format(bitpos)
```

or

```
if (slot >> (bitpos - 1)) & 1:
```

Your binary formatting code is overly verbose. Just use the `format()` function to create a binary string representation:

```
format(slot, '032b')
```

formats your binary value to a 0-padded 32-character binary string.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use slicing to get the correct digit.

```
bits = getBin(slot, 32)
bit = bits[bit_location-1:bit_location] #Assumes zero based values

print("bit: %i\n"%(bit))
```